# How do I dynamically add vertices in OpenGl?

Tags: c++, opengl

For example if I want to do something like this:

```
createTriangle(1.0,1.0); // Create triangle at (1,1)
```

How would I do this in code? I'm comfortable hardcoding this but if I want to do it dynamically how do I bind and fill my buffer and then bind it on display? Do I just add vertices to one big buffer? But then how do I do different transformations on different objects?

Edit: To clarify I'm asking how I create vertices and then insert them into the graphics pipeline.

Comment: I highly recommend [this e-book](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/).

Comment: I suggest you not to worry to much about those problems. If you want to draw triangle, just draw it, don't make super-uber-architectures if you don't really need to. Anyway, you can create one buffer with this triangle, store id, and then, by shader, translate it.

Comment: Big buffers aren't that good, as one may think. I don't know the details, but the problem is the same as in HDD/RAM and fragmentation, but on graphics card.

Comment: @Dupadupa What I'm trying to do though is create objects when and where I want them, to eventually make a game.

Comment: @Radek'daknok'Slupik Do you know where in this book I can find information pertinent to my question?

Comment: @bipolarpants From [here](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tut01%20Dissecting%20Display.html) and onwards explains how to get a triangle on the screen. Moving it is explained in chapter two.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a game, just do it :) Solving problems, without having one, is a problem! Have you planned the architecture, and have the idea for representing objects on scene, and its' components(physics, graphics)? If so, you probably have place in code, where you initialize scene(so let's create buffers there), and let 'engine' object(or just where you have main/render/animate/ loop) draw all of them. Depending on objects, and on how many models/3d/2d you have, you can store buffer' id in object(which is being drawn,and in render loop 'engine' object binds the buffer), or just simply store in 'engine' object.

Everything depends, what game you are making, and what problems, on what scale, do you face(for example,in that case you can create some bigger object manager, with groups of objects etc. The question is: do you really need these? They would probably make more bugs, and it will take more time to maintance the code, and afterall you will have to write this module again.) Don't make structures you don't need.

One rule may guide you: "Make things as simple as possible, but not simpler". And make games, not architectures that you want, just because UDK has one.

Comment: Hm you got me thinking, if I want to make an individual objects can I transform their vertices before passing them to the vertex shader? I'm struggling with how to integrate creating the vertices and then inserting them into the graphics pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not have one big buffer, but rather multiple buffers that share common things, such as shaders, transformations etc. Keeping the number of buffers down is, however, a good way to make the graphics run faster.

Comment: Hm, but lets say I create 3 triangles and add them all in the same buffer. I wouldn't be able to change each triangle's position independently would I?

Comment: Well, no - and yes. Each draw batch you put to render (most likely, each vertex buffer), will be drawn as a mesh by some mechanism (triangle strip, triangle fan etc -google it). Each vertex position, each vertex normal position, colours textures etc are individually possible to alter with a Vertex shader (to do object rotation, scaling, effects, textures, lighting, etc). The vertex shader is not really high level in the sense that you can write lots of C++ to alter the triangle. Parameters are passable to the shader however.